# Meshlab doesn't start due to failed GLEW initalization

Tags: glew, meshlab

On Ubuntu 16.04, I compiled MeshLab from the source (as described [here](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/meshlab/tree/master/src)). When I then try to run the created binary, I get the error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MLException'
  what():  MLSceneGLSharedDataContext: GLEW initialization failed

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Interestingly, I get the same error message when I run a Snap of Meshlab that I installed by `sudo snap install meshlab`.

I checked my GLEW libraries and they seem to be in place under `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so`. How can I detect where the error actually lies? Running the MeshLab binary with gdb didn't help me any further.

Answer (score 2):

Running `dmesg` showed me that I had a driver mismatch; I removed and re-installed the Nvidia drivers and after a reboot the problem disappeared. Both the compiled Meshlab and the Ubuntu snap are working fine now. The problem wasn't related to GLEW libraries.